# Ionic/Angular authentication system

Tags: ionic-framework

For the end of cycle Project of Our université we want to create an application where there are courses which make it possible to learn the development of application. We want to set up an authentication system and in the "home.page ts" file we have the Following problem: Module '"@angular/fire/auth"' has no exported member 'AngularFireAuth'.ts(2305)
import AngularFireAuth.

We have created a Firebase account and a Firebase project. We have created an Ionic/Angular project. We linked our Ionic/Angular app to Firebase. We have created a database. We have created fields in the "home.page.html" file. We have created three functions for registration, login and logout in the "home.page.ts" file.
We expected to create an application where there is an authentication system and application development courses.
What resulted is that the browser shows us "Cannot GET /".

Answer (score 0):

You have a mismatch in your Angularfire version and what your code is. Check your Angularfire version and firebase version. You may be on the latest in which uses different syntax.